# Firebase Storage returns 503 and an empty response when downloading public URL from Cloud Run

Tags: python, firebase-storage, google-cloud-run

I have a Cloud Run container that fetches a CSV file from a public Firebase Storage URL. The fetch is performed with Python `requests` module (i.e.: `requests.get()`).

Sometimes, apparently randomly, I get a 503 status code and the response has length zero:

```
{
  'X-GUploader-UploadID': 'XXX...',
  'Date': 'Tue, 19 Oct 2021 12:26:39 GMT',
  'Expires': 'Tue, 19 Oct 2021 12:26:39 GMT',
  'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0',
  'Content-Length': '0',
  'Server': 'UploadServer',
  'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  'Alt-Svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000'
}
```

Without re-uploading the file, and just trying a couple of minutes later, the same request may result in the expected non-empty response (with a 200 status code):

```
{
  'X-GUploader-UploadID': 'XXX...',
  'Expires': 'Tue, 19 Oct 2021 12:49:05 GMT',
  'Date': 'Tue, 19 Oct 2021 12:49:05 GMT',
  'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0',
  'Last-Modified': 'Wed, 04 Aug 2021 06:49:35 GMT',
  'ETag': '"9b6916..."',
  'x-goog-generation': '16280...',
  'x-goog-metageneration': '1',
  'x-goog-stored-content-encoding': 'identity',
  'x-goog-stored-content-length': '51666',
  'x-goog-meta-firebaseStorageDownloadTokens': '1954069b-...',
  'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
  'Content-Disposition': "inline; filename*=utf-8''csvdata",
  'x-goog-hash': 'crc32c=1LcP6Q==, md5=m1kWwxGuzZXeO4ZuA0NT5A==',
  'x-goog-storage-class': 'STANDARD',
  'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
  'Content-Length': '51666',
  'Vary': 'Origin',
  'Server': 'UploadServer',
  'Alt-Svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"'
}
```

Cannot reproduce with a request from my computer (i.e.: the file is always downloaded correctly). It seems it only happens from Cloud Run.

Any idea about what could be going on?

Comment: What is the HTTP STATUS value returned with the empty content-length example?

Comment: @JohnHanley I just updated the question title and description to note the 503 status code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloud Storage HTTP Status 503 means that Cloud Storage encountered an internal error. This usually means that you can try again later (e.g. wait ten seconds) and the request will succeed provided that the original request is valid.

The recommended solution is to try again using [truncated exponential backoff](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/retry-strategy#exponential-backoff).

Reference: [503 - Service Unavailable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#503_Service_Unavailable)

[UPDATE - see comments below]

If one instance works correctly and another identical instance consistently fails, then you have a service problem. You will need to open a support case with Google Cloud. Collect your logs to clearly specify what you commented so that Google knows what to diagnose.

Comment: The Cloud Run instance is running a Flask server, which stays alive for a couple of minutes or even longer if it is active. It seems that the same instance keeps failing with 503 status until it dies (i.e.: it seems like waiting a couple of seconds or even more does not help). Does that make any sense to you?

Comment: @Peque - Find the logs that show the same instance is getting 503. This will show the timings for each request. If your service is just firing one request after another, that is not a good retry strategy.

Comment: Thanks John. I did read the logs before posting. It is the same instance and, in my tests, I made sure no second instance was spawned. There are automatic retries implemented, with a delay of 1, 2, 3 seconds respectively. Then I executed manual retries that yielded the same results as long as they were executed in the same instance, and even after waiting 1 minute.

Comment: @Peque - If one instance works correctly and another identical instance consistently fails, then you have a service problem. You will need to open a support case with Google Cloud. Collect your logs to clearly specify what you commented so that Google knows what to diagnose.

Comment: Just like the problem appeared... It seems it disappeared (didn't happen in the last couple of hours). So I guess you were right about it being a service problem (presumably fixed). ^^